Is there "polarity" with a G10q lamp base?
I'm replacing an FC8-T9 fluorescent bulb with a new bypass LED bulb.  I found instructions which say to remove the ballast and connect the black wires on the G10q connector to the line (black) and the white wires to neutral (white.)  The problem is my connector has 4 white wires.  From surfing around, I've determined that the G10q has two flat sides and two rounded sides.   The wires on the flat sides are functionally equivalent (i.e., if they had a color, they'd be the same.)  My question is, how do I determine (either from the bulb or the failed ballast I'm removing) which side is hot and which is neutral, or does it even matter?

It doesn't matter; ac switches all the time anyway. On lamps with a E27 screw-in connector, you want the sleave to be neutral to avoid shocks when accidently touching it while screwing in a bulb, but on a fully-insulated connector like the one shown there's no such hazard.
